# How did they survive the jump?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

How is that Theon Greyjoy and Sansa Stark survived the jump in the first episode of the sixth season (*The Red Woman*) of *Game of Thrones*? It was a big distance between the wall and land. How did that happen?

Comment: Soft snow cushioned their fall no?

Comment: Please can you watch that episode again :) ?  There is huge distance between wall and land.

Comment: They jumped into the snow, breaking their fall.

Comment: When I saw that scene I couldn't help but compare it to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORP2FK60TEw) :)

Comment: I live on a ski resort and know that at that distance it would take a lot of soft fresh snow to cushion there fall from any injuries,. However if there was that much snow they would sink in it and be suffocated to death. So I'm still confused how they lived, and also how Tyrion survived the Harpies after denarys was taken by her dragon they were still outnumbered by a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the already published chapter](http://archive.is/eoIl) of *Winds of Winter*:

> "I saved her."  The outer wall of Winterfell was eighty feet high, but
>   beneath the spot where he had jumped the snows had piled up to a depth
>   of more than forty.  A cold white pillow.  The girl had taken the
>   worst of it.  (...)  Theon had landed on top of her, and broken some
>   of her ribs.  "I saved the girl," he said.  "We flew."

We can assume that in the show they also landed on a large snowdrift, it just wasn't presented on screen.

Comment: Leave it to Theon to drop 40 feet, land on top of Jeyne, and break some of her ribs but still claim that he saved her.